# How to use JPA in a existing project?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My team is working on a medium size application (OLTP style). We were interested by switching to JPA instead of only using JDBC queries. Mostly for performance and practical reason. I'm not looking for a tutorial that shows me how to create a persistence.xml or Entity class in Eclipse. What i would like to know is what would be the steps to convert all the database queries into the JPA format. I know that the whole application must use JPA.

Many programmers has worked on this project over the years, so not everyone has the same SQL knowledge or the same programming skills. So there must be in this application 1000+ customs queries, using multiple tables (something that native JPA does not support very well), or query that is selecting only a few fields in a table... This is getting a bit out of control and i think that JPA would create a nice toolbox to make sure that everyone is going the same direction.

What should i look for to make sure that i'm not going into a process (convertion) that will never end ? Some sort of guideline.

(Again, i'm not looking for programming exemples, nor Eclipse tutorial.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is convert you database schema into database model using JPA, you need to be clear what are the table, sequences, database objects that you are using in your existing application and start modeling all the schema with JPA you should consider use JPA annotation.

The step above will determine what will be your entities, embeddables and mapped superclass, their properties and the relationships they have, this step is very crucial as your logic will depends on the correctness of this model.

Then start looking for all the queries that are involved in your project, as you said that you have 1000+ queries consider use two scenario, convert all of them in JPQL queries or use a mix  between native queries and named queries, I really prefer to convert all in JPQL unless are very database dependent. A step you must follow is find all of them, probably are some existing tool that convert from SQL to JPQL but I believe is better idea make by your own.

Once you have queries and model for the database start the creation of your new DAO using JPA and EntityManager stuff, I should recommend extract the interface for your exisiting DAO and start moving to a JPA implementation using the same interface, this will avoid break some code on your own, don't forget unit and IT test for your new DAO.

Also with the above approach you could start moving the application module by module, DAO or by DAO does not require to move full application at once. This will give you a kind of process in which you will see some progress each time you finish a new DAO or module.

Not sure what you mean about programming examples, I think those are the required steps but each project is different from each other, so consider this as some kind of guidelines.

Comment: This was basically the kind of process I was thinking of, but it is nice to see the same thoughts elsewhere.